# Postgres: Create unique index on point within certain distance around it

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a folowing table in postgres 15

```sql
create table places
(
    id          bigint generated always as identity
        constraint pk_places
            primary key,
    name        varchar(128) not null,
    address     varchar(256) not null,
    region_name varchar      not null
        constraint fk_places_region_name_regions
            references regions
            on update cascade on delete restrict,
    coordinates geography(Point, 4326),
    constraint uq_places_name
        unique (name, region_name)
);

alter table places
    owner to postgres;

create index idx_places_coordinates
    on places using gist (coordinates);
```

I would like to create a unique index on **coordinates** field but exact value being unique makes little sence as coordinates might be specified with tiny tolerance to each other which effectively makes them non-unique. Question  - is it possible to construct unique index such a way that, for example, 1 point and another point that would be located for example in a radius of 100 meters around first 1 would be considered as 1 (same) point and in return would conjure up unique index constraint exception?

Thank you

Comment: what kind of select are you planning to so SELECT * FROM places WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_MakePoint(103.776047, 1.292149),location)  < 10' then your tabkle would already do what you needed, so i don't really get what you want to do with that index

Comment: @nbk. I would like to prevent inserts with coordinate that would be within 100 meters from already existing in table coordinate. Reason - most likelly they would represent the same object but with slight tolarance in coords taken from GPS

Comment: i think you should test before inserting, if the new entry already exsists in 100 meter, your problem would always be to make at some point the query about the distance, as you can have a referencepoint for every lication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an exclusion constraint for a small buffer around the points that prevents the bounding boxes of these buffers from overlapping:

```
ALTER TABLE places ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   (st_buffer(coordinates, 50, 'quad_segs=1')) WITH &&
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How did u calculate  100 metres into 0.00045 ? Perhaps it should be in meters ? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html  for Geography type?

Comment: Right. Use an appropriate distance; I was mostly concerned with the principle.

Comment: Does it need to be a generated column or would an expression index work as well?

Comment: @Bergi It seems that you are right. I wasn't aware that you can create an exclusion constraint on an expression (that is not possible with unique indexes, for example).